# AWS Cognito : How to terminate/close user session from server

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have written a lambda function and using `AdminInitiateAuthInput` API in my function to authenticate the user/initiate the user session.

I am using AWS API gateway.
I use the ID token received from the AdminInitiateAuthInput as the Authorization header while making API calls.

I want to terminate/logout the user, if he sends the request for logout.

Which is the API to close/terminate Cognito user session?

I came across `AdminUserGlobalSignOut` API, but it will terminate all the sessions for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an API to simply sign out a user from a session as admin. You can do this using the user [logout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html) API. However if you have to implement a way to terminate user from single session you can use the [AdminForgetDevice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminForgetDevice.html) API which will effectively terminate session from that device.